# Decreasing Arduino pro micro power consumption

Tags: power, arduino-micro, arduino-mini

I'm working on a project that involves sending GPS coordinates wirelessly from an arduino board to another one. I was thinking of using an arduino micro for this task. The problem is that I want it to last as long as possible on a lithium battery. I searched and found too many tutorials on how to decrease arduino pro mini power consumption, but I didn't find anything related to the arduino pro micro. So I was thinking, does the same procedure used to decrease the arduino pro mini consumption apply for the arduino pri micro?
Also, what microcontroller do you suggest for this project? (PIC, Arduino mini, micro, nano...)

Comment: how are you obtaining the GPS coordinates?

Comment: Most techniques apply to all Arduino boards. Remove the power led. Put the microcontroller in sleep-mode. Possibly remove/exchange the voltage regulator. Put attached devices to sleep, or remove power to them entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Bringing Down power consumption by taking the LED out and lowering the
>   clock ?**

Yes, you can do that! And you are okay with Arduino unless you want to complicate things more...If you want to check out other methods then you can check out the Microcontrollers Schematics and also the datasheets of their Components...